# Keep vertical scrollbar in a fixed position independent of horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, user-interface

I currently have a grid set up that looks something like this:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="headers"> <!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- ... --></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially what I'd like to do is place an `overflow-x` on the entire `grid-container` (so that scrolling horizontally will scroll both the headers and the rows together), but just place an `overflow-y: overlay` on the `row-container` (so that scrolling down will only scroll through the rows and keep the grid headers in a fixed position.

I was able to do that and it looks okay, however, the vertical scrollbar on the `row-container` is at the far right of the `row-container`. I'd like it to be visible and in a fixed position (similar to how it would look if you were to place an `overflow-y` on the entire `grid-container` except without affecting the headers).

Sorry I know I probably explained this poorly, but here's a JSFiddle that should hopefully illustrate the problem I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/4xwd5yzp/

Notice in that fiddle, you can only see the vertical scrollbar when you scroll to the end of the row-container.

Thank you in advance for any help. Ideally, I'd prefer a solution using just HTML + CSS, but I'm also open to use vanilla JS + jQuery if absolutely necessary.

EDIT: Here is an example of how it currently works (not ideal):
[image: Incorrect]

And here is a photo of how I want it to look:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can paint desired effect in Paint, or something like it? An image speaks a thousand words.

Comment: Try to set the width of grid and row in % rather than px. Check updated [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/4xwd5yzp/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, if you take the `overflow-y` style off of `.row-container` and add it to `.grid-container` and also add `position: sticky;` and `background: white;` to `.headers` then I believe it'll work how you want it to.

Comment: This ended up working! Initially I just wanted the scrollbar contained to row-container, but I think this is fine considering that it still only scrolls through the row-container elements (even though the scrollbar spans over the header container too).

Comment: Any ideas on how to prevent it from spanning over the header container?
If not, this solution is good enough I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Update the width in % rather than px.
`
    .grid-container {
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 200px;
      width: 99%x;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .row-container {
      height: 150px;
      width: 99%x;
      overflow-y: overlay;
    }
    .grid-cell {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 250px;
    }
    .headers {
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      height: 50px;
      width: 99%;
    }
    .row {
      border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
      height: 30px;
      width: 99%;
    }
  `
```